# High and low temperature array using iteration constructs

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I've been trying to write a program that prompts a user to enter the number of days they want to track between 3 to 10 days. If they enter a value less than two or greater than ten they should be met with an error message and the program should loop. After they've entered a value within the parameters, the program should use a for loop to prompt the user to enter the high and low temperatures until all of the values are input for the number of days the user chose. These values should also be stored in matching arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int day[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int high;
    int low;

    printf ("---===IPC Temperature Analyzer V2.0===---\n");

    printf ("Please enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);



    for(;i<10;i++) {
            printf("Day %d - High: \n", day[i]);
    }



return 0;

}
```

Right now I'm just focused on having the program output the number of days that the user chooses to enter and then having those days ask the user to input the highs and lows. The best I've managed so far is having the program output the days only for the highs, but it if the user enters, say 4, it will produce Day 4 - High:, Day 5 - High:, etc... instead of Day 1 - High;, Day 2 - High until it reaches the number of days which is 4 in this case. I'm also confused as to how I can have the user input the temperatures using a for loop. If anyone could provide some examples or even some insight into how to solve these issues, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: for loops must always start at a certain index. for (i=0;i<10;i++). You will get an error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `int i`. The same variable is being used as loop index as well as it is being used to take the input from the user. When user says `4`, `i` is assigned to `4` and the loop runs from i = 4 to i = 9. Hence this observation.

> it will produce Day 4 - High:, Day 5 - High:, etc... instead of Day 1 - High;, Day 2 - High until it reaches the number of days which is 4 in this case

Now to do what you want to do, you can the take the input from the user in a different variable say `limit` and then use the loop like this

`for (i=0; i < limit; i++)`

Also, you will need to validate that the value of `limit` is not more than the size of your array `day[]`

Comment: I updated my code to include your suggestion and it's working now, thanks! I added 'int limit' to separate user input from i and added a 'while' loop to limit the new value to the size of the array.